# The Green-Julg Theorem

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kk-theory

I am currently trying to understand the general Green-Julg theorem, where $G$ is a compact group, $A$ and $B$ are $G$-$C^*$-algebras, and where $G$ acts trivially on $A$. The Green-Julg theorem states that there is an isomorphism 
$$ \mathrm{KK}^G(A,B) \rightarrow \mathrm{KK}(A, B\rtimes G).$$
Unfortunately, in all of the papers I can find, it's always the special case $A=\mathbb{C}$. Does anybody know a good paper where a proof is given for the general case?

Thank you.

Comment: If true what you say, I think you can simply copy the usual Green-Julg proof and inherit the additional $\varphi:A\rightarrow L(E)$ of the Kasparov cycle $(\varphi,E)\in KK^G(A,B)$. Because $G$ acts trivially, $A \rtimes G = A \otimes G$ under the descent in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

For $G$ a finite group, this is part 3 of Theorem 1.22 in the preprint [A stable ∞-category for equivariant KK-theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.13372) by Ulrich Bunke, Alexander Engel and Markus Land.

More precisely, they prove an adjunction $\operatorname{Res}_G: \operatorname{KK} \rightleftarrows \operatorname{KK}^G: - \rtimes G$ of $\infty$-categories, where $\operatorname{Res}_G: \operatorname{KK} \to \operatorname{KK}^G$ is induced by the functor $C^*{\rm Alg} \to GC^*{\rm Alg}$ that equips a $C^*$-algebra $A$ with the trivial $G$-action. This induces an adjunction on homotopy categories. If $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra and $B$ is a $G$-$C^*$-algebra, this gives  desired isomorphism
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{KK}^G(\operatorname{Res}_GA,B) \cong\mathrm{KK}(A, B\rtimes G).
\end{aligned}